# Python list(or dict) of random list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, numpy, random

I would create a list or a dictionnary "p0" containing lists with random numbers at a particular index. I do not understand what happens in this short code:

```
import numpy as np

p0={}
a=[0,0,0]

for i in range(10):
    a[1]= np.random.uniform(0,i) 
    print a
    p0[i] = a 
    print p0[i]
print "\n final p0: ",p0
```

the final `p0` only contains `10` times the last iteration result... and is different from the previous (in the loop) `p0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass `a` to `p0[i]` you're passing a reference to the list. So you have to make a copy out of it when you insert it into the dictionary which you can do like this:

```
p0[i] = list(a)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sevanteri ! that works pretty well!